# Duplicate action at the same time of NSTimer?

Tags: iphone, ios, nstimer

Below is my source code,i don't know why.
Can anyone explain to me?.Thank so much

```
- (void)onTimer:(NSTimer *)timer {
    long currentPlaybackTime = self.player.currentPlaybackTime;
    int currentHours = (currentPlaybackTime / 3600);
    int currentMinutes = ((currentPlaybackTime / 60) - currentHours*60);
    int currentSeconds = (currentPlaybackTime % 60);
    self.currentLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%02d:%02d", currentHours, currentMinutes, currentSeconds];
    if( currentMinutes > 0 && currentSeconds == 5)
    {
        //duplicate action at here.
        NSLog(@"Make a thread to decrypt file buffer");
        [self bufferEncryption];
    }
}
```

Call timer:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

When i try with:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Timer calls only one round.Why?

Regards,

Comment: Perhaps OP doesn't remember writing it.  He wants to know why it exists :).

Comment: Sorry, the problem is,when second is 5,i've two debug log lines.  NSLog(@"Make a thread to decrypt file buffer");
NSLog(@"Make a thread to decrypt file buffer");

Answer (score 2):

Answering your comment....you call your timer every HALF second, so `(currentPlaybackTime % 60)` will evaluate to 5 twice (mod will return an INTEGER).  Once for 5 and once again for 5.5.  That is why it gets called twice.